# Mysql - cannot insert a column name conatining colons to a table

Tags: python, mysql, emoji, reserved-words

I'm working on a project of a simple chatting app, using python. In order to save the data of each client, I use a MySql database. When a new member signs up, a column is added to one of my tables, in the database. Everything worked fine. I decided to support usernames containing emojis. I thought it would be useful to convert the emojis to strings. For that, I use the demojize() function:

```
client_name = qwer
name2save = emoji.demojize(client_name)
# name2save = qwer:winking_face_with_tongue:
```

Then, in order to add the column to my table, I use the follwing SQL qwery:

```
"ALTER TABLE private_chats ADD COLUMN '" + emoji.demojize(name2save) + "' TEXT(6000)"
```

When I run the qwery I get the follwing error:

```
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''qwer:winking_face_with_tongue:' TEXT(6000)' at line 1
```

I think the problem is the colons in that username.
My question is how am I supposed to add a column name, containing colons or any other reserved chars, to a MySql table?

Comment: The emoji translates to `qwer:winking_face_with_tongue:` so your sql query will be `ADD COLUMN 'qwer:winking_face_with_tongue:' TEXT(6000)` which is not a valid column name. Regardless - adding a new column for each user that register to your system is really not a good approach. You should have a `users` table with the columns `id | username`  (and maybe more), and inside the private_chats - have a column of the `user_id` and just save the id of the relevant user inside.

Comment: @Dekel thanks for the advice! I'll use it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure but you may not use single quotation marks

```
'
```

for column identifiers but backtick

```
`
```

instead.

Comment: Yes - switching from single quotes to backticks works for me.